# Java stream collect to Map<String, Map<Integer, MyObject>>

Tags: java

I'm using Java 11 and I have a `List<MyObject>` called `myList` of the following object:

```
public class MyObject {
  private final String personalId;
  private final Integer rowNumber;
  private final String description;
<...>
}
```

and I want using streams to collect these objects into a `Map<String, Map<Integer, List<MyObject>>>`
(with following syntax: `Map<personalId, Map<rowNumber, List<MyObject>>>`) and **I don't want to use** `Collectors.groupBy()`, because it has issues with `null`
values.

I tried to do it using `Collectors.toMap()`, but it seems that it is not possible to do it

```
myList
.stream()
.Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getPersonalId(), s -> Collectors.toMap(t-> s.getRowNumber(), ArrayList::new))
```

My question is it possible to make a `Map<String, Map<Integer, List<MyObject>>>` object using streams **without using Collectors.groupBy()** or should I write a full method myself?

Comment: Why do you want to use a new Map for every element in the first place? If I got your question right you only need on entry for every `personalId`. So cou could just use a pair: `Map<String, Pair<Integer, MyObject>>`.

Comment: To be more explicit, would that be a `Map<personalId, Map<rowNumber, MyObject>>`, or a `Map<rowNumber, List<MyObject>>`? The former would just need a `Function.identity()` for the second parameter of the second `#toMap` call, while the latter would be a simpler stream to write. Either way, I'm not sure how these would be useful.

Comment: You can't do `s.personalId` possibly because it's private

Comment: `public class MyObject(){}` is also wrong syntax

Comment: Could you give an example why `groupingBy` does not work for you? `groupingBy` may be a solution just working fine, if you can fix the null problems beforehand.

Comment: @Rogue Is the `personalId` unique? In that case I believe a person can't have multiple row numbers. For the second type this is not possible with a stram because you have multible entries with the same row, so you just need to create a new list for the first element and then add the other elements. Am I right that the datastructure of the list is `List<MyObject>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I would create the maps first and then loop through the elements in this list as shown:

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> rows = new HashMap<>(); 
list.forEach(element -> rows.computeIfAbsent(element.personalId, s -> new ArrayList<>()).add(element));
```

You can use `computeIfAbsent` in order to create a new list/map as a value of the map before you can put your data in.

---

The same is with the second data type you created:

```
Map<String, Map<Integer, MyObject>> persons = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(element -> persons.computeIfAbsent(element.personalId, s -> new HashMap<>()).put(element.rowNumber, element));
```

---

Here is a way to solve this with streams. But note that the objects must have a unique `personId`/`rowNumber`:

```
Map<String, List<MyObject>> rows = list.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(element -> element.personalId, 
        element -> new ArrayList<MyObject>(Arrays.asList(element))));
```

As well as for the other map:

```
    Map<String, Map<Integer, MyObject>> persons = list.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(e -> e.personalId, 
            e -> new HashMap<>(Map.of(e.rowNumber, e))));
```

Comment: I invested to much of my time in pursuing a solution with streams. What I was trying to craft was a one list.stream()... thing and at the end I wanted to get a Map<String, Map<Integer,List<MyObject>>> object. But now looking at your solution it feels that I wasted a lot of time for something that which could be accomplished so easily. Thanks

Comment: @treo I just found a way to do this with streams if you are still interested. Will update this post soon.

Comment: @treo It seems like even OP doesn't really care that the first two snippets of code which make use `getOrDefault()` actually doesn't populate the map, both maps remain **empty!** The third, and the fourth snippets would produce an `EllegalStateException` if there are objects with duplicated properties in the list. And in case if there no duplicated `id` the third map doesn't make sense and the fourth happens to be overcomplicated (there would be no need using nested map, it would be impractical).

Comment: @treo And in case if **duplicates are expected** then this doesn't answer the question on how to generate a map having required structure.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko thank you for looking at this post more carefully. I did include some mistakes late night. 1) I somhow mistaked `getOrDefault()` with `getOrAddDefault()` wich is not present with maps and forgot to test the last change. It needs to be replaced with `computeIfAbsent()`. 2) The author hasn't asnwerd the question, which variables are unique and which arent yet. so for the second attempt I assume that there is no same `personalId` and `rowNumber` in combination. Otherwise the second datatype doesn't work. 3) I added a notice that the streams only work with unique values.

Answer (score 1):

> `Map<String, Map<Integer, List<MyObject>>>` object using streams without using `Collectors.groupingBy()`

By looking at the map type, I can assume that a combination of `personalId` and `rowNumber` is **not** unique, i.e. there could be multiple occurrences of each combination (otherwise you don't need to group objects into lists). And there could be different `rowNumber` associated with each `personalId`. Only if these conclusions correct, this nested collection might have a very vague justification for existence.

Otherwise, you probably can substitute it multiple collections for different use-cases, for `Map<String, MyObject>` - object by *id* (if every id is unique):

```
Map<String, MyObject> objById = myList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        MyObject::getPersonalId,
        Function.identity()
    ));
```

I'll proceed assuming that you really need such a nested collection.

Now, let's address the issue with `groupingBy()`. This collector uses internally `Objects.requireNonNull()` to make sure that a *key* produced by the *classifier* function is *non-null*.

If you tried to use and failed because of the hostility to *null-keys*, that implies that either `personalId`, or `rowNumber`, or both can be `null`.

Now let's make a small detour and pose the question of what does it imply if a property that considered to be significant (you're going to use `personalId` and `rowNumber` to access the data, hence they are definitely important) and `null` means first of all?

`null` signifies the absence of data and nothing else. If in your application `null` values have an additional special meaning, that's a design flaw. If properties that are significant for managing your data for some reason appear to be `null` you need to fix that.

You might claim that you're quite comfortable with `null` values. If so let pause for a moment and imagine a situation: person enters a restaurant, orders a soup and asks the waiter to bring them a fork instead of spoon (because of they have a negative experience with a spoon, and they are enough comfortable with fork).

`null` isn't a data, it's an indicator of the absence of data, storing `null` is an antipattern. If you're storing `null` it obtains a special meaning because you're forced to treat it separately.

To replace `personalId` and `rowNumber` that are equal to `null` with default values we need only one line of code.

```
public static void replaceNullWithDefault(List<MyObject> list,
                                          String defaultId,
                                          Integer defaultNum) {
    
    list.replaceAll(obj -> obj.getPersonalId() != null && obj.getRowNumber() != null ? obj :
        new MyObject(Objects.requireNonNullElse(obj.getPersonalId(), defaultId),
            Objects.requireNonNullElse(obj.getRowNumber(), defaultNum),
            obj.getDescription()));
}
```

After that can use the proper tool instead eating soup with a fork, I mean we can process the list data with `groupingBy()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(
            new MyObject("id1", 1, "desc1"),
            new MyObject("id1", 1, "desc2"),
            new MyObject("id1", 2, "desc3"),
            new MyObject("id1", 2, "desc4"),
            new MyObject("id2", 1, "desc5"),
            new MyObject("id2", 1, "desc6"),
            new MyObject("id2", 1, "desc7"),
            new MyObject(null, null, "desc8")
        ));
    
    replaceNullWithDefault(myList, "id0", 0); // replacing null values
    
    Map<String, Map<Integer, List<MyObject>>> byIdAndRow = myList // generating a map
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            MyObject::getPersonalId,
            Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getRowNumber)
        ));
    
    byIdAndRow.forEach((k, v) -> { // printing the map
        System.out.println(k);
        v.forEach((k1, v1) -> System.out.println(k1 + " -> " + v1));
    });
}
```

*Output:*

```
id0
0 -> [MyObject{'id0', 0, 'desc8'}]
id2
1 -> [MyObject{'id2', 1, 'desc5'}, MyObject{'id2', 1, 'desc6'}, MyObject{'id2', 1, 'desc7'}]
id1
1 -> [MyObject{'id1', 1, 'desc1'}, MyObject{'id1', 1, 'desc2'}]
2 -> [MyObject{'id1', 2, 'desc3'}, MyObject{'id1', 2, 'desc4'}]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/t2V)

Now, please pay attention to the usage of `groupingBy()` did you notice its conciseness. That's the **right tool** which allows generating even such a clumsy nested map.

And now we're going to eat the soup with a fork! All `null` properties would be used as is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(
            new MyObject("id1", 1, "desc1"),
            new MyObject("id1", 1, "desc2"),
            new MyObject("id1", 2, "desc3"),
            new MyObject("id1", 2, "desc4"),
            new MyObject("id2", 1, "desc5"),
            new MyObject("id2", 1, "desc6"),
            new MyObject("id2", 1, "desc7"),
            new MyObject(null, null, "desc8")
        ));
    
    Map<String, Map<Integer, List<MyObject>>> byIdAndRow = myList // generating a map
        .stream()
        .collect(
            HashMap::new,
            (Map<String, Map<Integer, List<MyObject>>> mapMap, MyObject next) ->
                mapMap.computeIfAbsent(next.getPersonalId(), k -> new HashMap<>())
                    .computeIfAbsent(next.getRowNumber(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
                    .add(next),
            (left, right) -> right.forEach((k, v) -> left.merge(k, v,
                (oldV, newV) -> {
                    newV.forEach((k1, v1) -> oldV.merge(k1, v1,
                        (listOld, listNew) -> {
                            listOld.addAll(listNew);
                            return listOld;
                        }));
                    return oldV;
                }))
        );
    
    byIdAndRow.forEach((k, v) -> { // printing the map
        System.out.println(k);
        v.forEach((k1, v1) -> System.out.println(k1 + " -> " + v1));
    });
}
```

*Output:*

```
null
null -> [MyObject{'null', null, 'desc8'}]
id2
1 -> [MyObject{'id2', 1, 'desc5'}, MyObject{'id2', 1, 'desc6'}, MyObject{'id2', 1, 'desc7'}]
id1
1 -> [MyObject{'id1', 1, 'desc1'}, MyObject{'id1', 1, 'desc2'}]
2 -> [MyObject{'id1', 2, 'desc3'}, MyObject{'id1', 2, 'desc4'}]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/t2W)